# Is it possible in VBA to do these two IF statements in just one?

Tags: vba

Is it possible to do the following two IF statements in just one?

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Config") _
.Range("B3:B8"), .Cells(r - a, 3)) = 1 Or .Cells(r, 3) = "" Then
            
     If .Cells(r, 3).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 And _
        .Cells(r, 3).Interior.ColorIndex <> 2 Then
            
               'CONTENT
                
      Else: desired_activity = False
      End If

End If
```

Comment: `If ( ... Or ...) And ... And ... Then`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I didn't know that using parenthesis in VBA was allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't. The more you cram into an expression, the more reasons it has to fail. All these member calls each have multiple reasons to fail all by themselves; moreover, "logical" operators don't short-circuit in VBA, which means the entire expression gets evaluated: when the left-side of an `And` operator evaluates to `False`, the result isn't known until the right-side is evaluated too.

That means VBA code has every reason to *avoid* combining conditional expressions into terse one-liners.

But yes, it's possible, using parentheses to help with the order of operations - I'd warmly recommend pulling the conditional count into its own expression though:

```vb
Dim conditionalCount As Long
conditionalCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Config").Range("B3:B8"), .Cells(r - a, 3))

If (conditionalCount = 1 Or .Cells(r, 3) = "") And ( _
     .Cells(r, 3).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 And _
     .Cells(r, 3).Interior.ColorIndex <> 2) Then

    '...
            
Else

    '...

End If
```

Comment: Really nice recommendation. Thanks!